# What is a DOCVARIABLE in word

Tags: ms-word, docvariable

What is a `DOCVARIABLE` in Microsoft Word 2003? How do I set it? How do I make it display in my Word document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How do I make it display in my word document:

Insert->Field->Category:DocumentAutomation->Field Names:DocVariable->Field COdes Button-> Then enter the name of the variable.

Answer (score 7):

> You can use the Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Variables collection to set and retrieve the contents of a string variable in a Word document or template.
>
> Also, you can use the DocVariable field to retrieve the value of a document variable after it has been set to display within a Word document.

Source: [How to store and retrieve variables in Word documents](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306281)

```
Sub GetSetDocVars()

Dim fName As String
fName = "Jeff Smith"
' Set contents of variable "fName" in a document using a document
' variable called "FullName".
ActiveDocument.Variables.Add Name:="FullName", Value:=fName
' Retrieve the contents of the document variable.
MsgBox ActiveDocument.Variables("FullName").Value

End Sub
```

Comment: But like where does this code goes into? is it a Word script or something?

Comment: This method will cause errors to be thrown if the method is run more than once.  VBA (tested in Word 2013) will allow you to create/set values on the fly using for example `ActiveDocument.Variables("FieldName").Value = fieldValue`

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for an answer to this question.
Created a small script to display all ActiveDocument.Variables

Here is it:

```
Sub GetVariables()
    ' Declaration of output variavle, which is a string
    Dim output As String
    output = ""

    For Each Variable In ActiveDocument.Variables
        ' & is used for string concatenation.
        output = output & Variable.Name & " = " & Variable & vbNewLine
    Next

    MsgBox output
End Sub
```