# Is it possible to add some data to a Word document?

Tags: .net, ms-word, ms-office, word-2007

Is it possible to add (thru the MS Word object model? or by editing file) some custom data (another file maybe?)

Will be that data preserved after opening, changing and saving document in MS Word ?

(I need to put some tracking data in docx during some report export, custom data will be used again during import)

Comment: you mean data that is not actually part of the document? That seems counterintuitive. I wouldn't expect a word processor to process, generate or preserve data not related to my document.

Comment: data should be attached to file/document,  but not accessible (easly) by user in Word application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for all responses.
I used custom properties to add some UserID data to generated documents, it's enough to 'trace' document and be able to import it later.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhxe2d75.aspx

Comment: This is an acceptable solution. The risk is that end-users have access to this and may delete your custom properties. So, its best your code does not break if properties you use do not exist.

Comment: they couldn't just upload again document with changed values (or without them). i don't remember know how it worked.

Answer (score 13):

Yes. It's rather straightforward, but as far as I know, not documented (at all or very well). Say you want to add an **.ini** file to your your Office doc (.docx, .xslx, .pptx) to be "carried around" with your document (i.e. you send your **.docx** to someone over email and want the ***yourfile*.ini** you've added to stay with the ***yourdoc*.docx** even if the person opening the DOCX makes some changes and then saves it and sends it back to you).

1. Rename your document's extention to
   **.zip**. Unzip it.
2. In the root folder, find the
   **[Content_Types].xml** file and open it.
3. Right under the `<Type/>` root
   element, add `<Default
   Extension="ini"
   ContentType="custom/ini"/>` (note -
   for another file, just make sure the
   extention matches the file you're
   going to add and the attribute
   `Extention` matches that. For the
   `ContentType` attribute, that can be
   anything at all).
4. Now add your ***filename*.ini** file to the
   package. You can add it anywhere -
   the root, the **/word** path, a new
   folder like **/word/MyIniFiles**.
5. Next, set up a relationship between
   your file and the document. If you
   don't, the file won't carry with the
   document. Navigate to the
   **\word_rels\document.xml.rels** file,
   and add under `<Relationships/>`
   something like `<Relationship
   Id="rd1"
   Type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2007/relationships/ini"
   Target="abcpy.ini" />` where the
   attribute `Id` is a unique name in your `Type` (best to stick with rID*X* or something like that), `Type` reflects a URI (of
   just about anything) and `Target` is
   the relative path of the file you
   added. I added **abcpy.ini** to the
   **/word** folder which is in the same
   root as **document.xml**, so my
   relative path is just the file name.
   Had I added it to a folder under
   **/word** that was called **myIniFiles**,
   the `Target` would be
   **myIniFiles/abcpy.ini**
6. Save everything. Rezip your file from the root and name the document back to your original name and the
   extention back to **.docx**. Copy/paste over the original file. Done.

If you have the Open XML Package Editor (part of [VSTO Power Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=46B6BF86-E35D-4870-B214-4D7B72B02BF9&displaylang=en) for VS2008 or recently released [stand-alone](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/450a00e3-5a7d-4776-be2c-8aa8cec2a75b) for VS 2010), you can use VS to do some of this work for you, but it's essentially the same. Different terminology though like `Target` equals `Name`, etc.

Note that this isn't some kind of hack. Microsoft themselves use this very same technique in Office 2010 for images modified with the new "Artistic Effects" - the original image file is ported to an [HDPhoto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_XR) type and modified images are saved as png or jpg (and those are the ones that are displayed in the client). The hdphoto (with a `.wdp` extension) travels with the document, but is never actually used in display in Word, PowerPoint, etc.

Comment: Nice idea, but unfortunately this no longer works, if it ever did, for Excel documents. The custom information is removed when the file is saved with Excel.

Comment: @Chazg76, it worked just fine for me based on the instructions above in Excel, including after making changes in Excel to a cell value and saving again. Only thing I did differently was in step #5 above was use an updated value as the `Type`, i.e. `<Relationship Id="rd5" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/relationships/ini" Target="myIniFiles/abcpy.ini" />`. Version: Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 (Version 2306) 64-bit. I then sent it to a different computer with Excel, opened it, changed a cell/saved. Unzipped. My .ini file is still there.

Comment: Thanks @ToddMain for the info. I'll give it another go and let you know how I get on.

Comment: OK just tried it and it works! Apologies for my initial comment saying that it did not work! Many thanks for your help on this.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible. Word has a feature that allows you to embed an arbitrary XML document into your Word document. This feature is called *Custom XML*.

The embedded document is retained when the document is edited and can also be accessed from within the document, either programmatically using VBA, or using the Content Controls introduced with Word 2007.

Note that Word requires the embedded content to be XML, but that doesn't restrict you to pure XML data as you can use base64 encoding to embed binary content into XML.

MSDN has a sample in C# that shows you how to add a Custom XML part to a .docx file:

> **[How to: Add Custom XML Parts to Documents Without Starting Microsoft Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608597.aspx)**

Comment: Didn't Microsoft have some legal problems around the technology you are describing? As far as I can remember (from somewhere), they were required to either disable it with a patch, or pay some reimbursements. Do you have any information of this kind, or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Shade: I think you're referring to http://blogs.technet.com/b/gray_knowlton/archive/2010/01/11/regarding-custom-xml-patch-distribution-and-availability.aspx. Lots of good reading from that link.

Comment: @razor: If you're looking for adding an XML file, this answer is the correct one. If you're looking at any other file type, see above. +1 for 0xA3.

Comment: @Shade: Just to make Otaku's remark a bit clearer: This way of adding custom, arbitraty XML parts to a document is *not* the same technology as the custom XML *markup* that Microsoft had to remove. It's very confusing as the names used are very similar.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. I see the difference now.

Answer (score 2):

No, if you add anything to this zip file Word will start complaining about file corruption.
But don't reinvent the wheel. Word documents can have multiple different document properties. Just use that.
http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/word-help/add-property-information-to-a-document-HA010163766.aspx

Comment: Thanks for all information ! There are very useful.
For now, I've used Custom Properties to mark document with some UserID data.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of being complete, you can also use the field **DocVariable**. This is actually a bookmark in the same way the document properties but a more open ended, at least for naming. These are best for relatively small bits of information. If you want to add a complete file, the other methods might be better.

See:

[What is a DOCVARIABLE in word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205179/what-is-a-docvariable-in-word)