Word Macro to convert RTF-string into table or image
I work with macros in Word. The input to the macro is a data set that may contain an RTF object. It could be plain text, a table or an image (maybe something else, but that’s what I’m focusing on). I've tried inserting RTF as is, but that just inserts the encoded string ({\rtf1 and all...) into the document.
Sub InsertSPElement(iRow, arrTables)
    Dim text, full_text As String
    text = arrTables(iRow, 8)
    full_text = arrTables(iRow, 10) ' RTF String
    
    With Selection
        If StrComp(arrTables(iRow, 6), "Important", 1) = 0 Then
            .InsertAfter text:=text
            .Font.Bold = True
            '.Range.SetListLevel Level:=CInt(arrTables(iRow, 3))
            .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Header " & arrTables(iRow, 3))
            .InsertParagraphAfter
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
            
            If Len(full_text) > 0 Then
                .InsertAfter text:=full_text
                .Font.Bold = False
                .InsertParagraphAfter
                .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Is it possible to somehow take a string from rtf and transform it into something that it originally was, working only through a macro? I don't have access to the document call because it happens through a third party application
I tried just put rtf-string through .InsertAfter, but it don't work at all

If you can save your RTF to disk, you should be able to insert that.Alternatively, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354299/embed-contents-of-a-rtf-file-into-a-docx-file-using-openxml-sdk

@jonsson unfortunately, i can't do this

If you can do what you want manually then do it with the Macro Recorder switched on and work from there.

Think the SO link I posted is still relevant because you should be able to build an OOXML document with an RTF alt chunk in memory and insert it without saving to disk.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63716400/injecting-rtf-code-in-the-clipboard-to-paste-into-ms-word-as-rtf-text-via-a-vba/63721540?noredirect=1#comment112698372_63721540
