# Can I store custom XML data in an xlsx file using CustomXmlPart?

Tags: excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am using the OpenXML SDK to manipulate my Excel files.

I'd like to store some custom XML data in the xlsx file (*not* in the sheet cells) in a way that survives a roundtrip through Excel.

Is it possible to do this with the `CustomXmlPart` class? Or some other class? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CustomXmlParts are one way to do it. But here's another set of ways: [How can I embed any file type into Microsoft Word using OpenXml 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322247/how-can-i-embed-any-file-type-into-microsoft-word-using-openxml-2-0) (Word/Excel = same concept)